# Stripplot and lineplot weird result

Tags: python, seaborn

When I use lineplot or stripplot it works well. But using both the median is shifted; I don't understand why! Thank you for your help.

```
sns.lineplot(x='quality', y='alcohol', data=df, estimator=np.median, err_style=None)
sns.stripplot(x='quality', y='alcohol', data=df, jitter=True, color='red', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='none')
```

[stripplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbl2k.png)

[lineplot+stripplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjmNX.png)

[lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Zca.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that your first plot is creating an x axis with 0 to n range, and relabeling those x tick with a list of integers from 3 to n, then when the second chart or the stripplot plots on top of this x axis it is using the original number therefore xtick 3 for this new chart starts on labelled xtick 6.  Hence the offset.

One way to do correct this is to create a xaxis with a predefined range and then plot both charts on this predefined scale, see example below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [10, 12, 15, 18, 19, 26]

#First axes creates the error in graphing
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y, ax=ax[0])
sns.stripplot(x=x, y=y, ax=ax[0])

#Second axes shows correction
xplot = range(len(x))
sns.lineplot(x=xplot,y=y, ax=ax[1])
sns.stripplot(x, y=y, ax=ax[1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However I don't understand how to apply it. I've a file with 4898 rows with 7 qualities and lineplot compute the median value (of alcohol variable) for each quality.

Comment: Finally, I did it thanks to your post and the offset idea.  labels, uniques = pd.factorize(df['quality'], sort = True)
sns.lineplot(x=labels, y=df['alcohol'], estimator=np.median, err_style=None, color='black')
sns.stripplot(x='quality', y='alcohol', data=df, jitter=True, color='red', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='none')